# How do I create a patch from one branch to another using only a subset of the files that were changed?

Tags: git, diff

That is, suppose I want a patch that will take me from `branch1` to `branch2`, but I only care about files `foo1.c` and `foo2.c`, whereas other files also changed between the two branches.

**How can I make a patch including exactly these two files?**

If I just do `git diff branch1 branch2 > Change.patch`, I will get all the files.

If I just do `git diff branch1:foo1.c branch2:foo1.c > Change.patch`, I only get the patch for one file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git diff branch1:foo1.c branch2:foo1.c > Change.patch`, i.e. the same file on each branch?

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- foo1.c foo2.c > change.patch
```